# Хелпер по созданию типовых таблиц в миграциях laravel

Tags: php, laravel

На разных проектах есть таблицы нескольких типов (регистры, документы, справочная информация и т.д.), у которых всегда будет один и тот же набор полей + какие-то уникальные поля

Есть ли возможность в laravel создать хелпер по созданию типовых таблиц, в котором заранее будут определены поля + возможность добавлять узкие поля непосредственно в самой миграции?

Если есть, буду признателен за пример.
Спасибо

Comment: О каком хелпере идёт речь? И что еще за узкие поля?

Comment: Идея в следующем: вы хотите создать таблицу типа "документ". У всех таблиц типа документ есть поле, например, "number" и "date". Но также к этой таблице вам нужно добавить какие-то специфичные именно для этой таблицы поля. Вы создаете миграцию, дергаете метод по созданию таблицы типа "документ" (в котором уже перечислены общие поля), и перечисляете только специфичные поля. Это может помочь не дублировать каждый раз общие поля в миграциях для таблиц определенного типа, а также позволит проставлять общие поля по умолчанию

Comment: Думаю использование [trait](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/how-to-refactor-common-columns-in-migration-in-laravel) должно вам помочь.